# Can’t Make the navbar in mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile-website

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark navbar-transparent fixed-top sticky-navigation" id="lambda-navbar">
    <div class="header"><img src="images/ssn_logo.png" alt="logo" style="max-width: 15%;position:absolute;left:2.5%;"/><h1></h1></div>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"></a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right border-0" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span data-feather="menu"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline">

        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I can’t make this in mobile view. If I try to make it responsive, the navbar is not visible in mobile view.

Comment: There is an collapse tag around your navigation which gets hidden on mobile devices, you can then show your navigation by clicking on your navbar-toggler which needs jquery and bootstrap.js to work.

Comment: How can I remove that toggler to make both the buttons appear on the navbar itself rather than collapsing and showing

Comment: Remove the button because you won't be needing it then and also remove those classes `collapse navbar-collapse`. I created an answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

In mobile view there is a collapse class added to nav bar that sets display: none. It gets overridden only above 768px which is why its hidden in small screens

```css
  @media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-expand-md .navbar-collapse {
    display: -ms-flexbox !important;
    display: flex !important;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: auto;
    flex-basis: auto;
    
    
    
 .collapse {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: but it is changing the orientation of the page,the entire content in the navbar gets changed and not it was as it was used to be

Comment: Please update the qn on what needs to be achieved here

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your navigation to collapse on mobile just remove the `navbar-toggler` button and the `collapse navbar-collapse` classes so your navigation stays visible.

Comment: Great.Seems Working,Just one more question, SInce it is visible now ,the navbar is expanded a bit more than usual so one button is one line the other in the other line.How to fix this

Comment: You don't have enough space to fit everything on a mobile screen that's why one button is pushed to a new line. Remove the `Choose your login:` text on mobile and your buttons will fit. You can do this by adding the classes `d-none d-sm-block` to the h4 tag.

Comment: Is there any way to lessen the size of the button so the whole content fits in?